# How to set "label 3" with the same percentage that "label 1" in this form?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

I would like set "label 3" with the same width that "label 1". The input width, the rest of the page (see code)

It's possible?

Thanks.

[image]

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-6">
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="name" class="col-6">LABEL 1:</label>
<div class="input-group col-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="name" class="col-6">LABEL 2:</label>
<div class="col-6">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" type="text">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>      

<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="name" class="col-3">LABEL 3:</label>
<div class="input-group col-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting a `row` beside `form-group`, add another `div` that have a `form-row`, something like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="name" class="col-6">LABEL 1:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="name" class="col-6">LABEL 2:</label>
        <div class="col-6">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="name" class="col-3">LABEL 3:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the issue is mostly the padding of `row`, but not sure. I just rearranged it properly, by separating `row`/`form-row`

Comment: If I change the sizes? For example col-3 and col-9 /// col-3 and col-9. How to set label 3?

Comment: Sizes of what element?

Comment: label and input-group

Comment: There are three `<label>` and `.input-group` in the code, which exactly are you referring to? And since **Label 3** is already `col-3`, are you referring to **Label 1** and **Label 2**?

Comment: Regardless, I suggest you try first trying whatever you want to change, then ask again if you encountered a problem. This answer is only meant for the current question.

Comment: <label for="name" class="col-3">LABEL 1:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
        </div>

 <label for="name" class="col-3">LABEL 2:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
        </div>

Comment: col-3 and col-9 and label 3 like label 1

Comment: I understand, that is kinda hard. Although like I said, that is now a separate question, so I suggest opening another question asking that, since that is not really your original question